# How to get - number of threads per process?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, process, threads

This is one Ubuntu 9.10 server.

Also how to see memory usage per process?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268680/how-can-i-monitor-the-active-thread-count-of-a-process-jvm-on-linux

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
ps axo pid,ppid,rss,vsz,nlwp,cmd
```

Output columns:

- pid - Process ID
- ppid - Parent Process ID
- rss - Resident Set Size - physical memory
- vsz - Virtual Set Size - virtual memory
- nlwp - Number of Light Weight Processes - thread count
- cmd - Command

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to show the memory use of a single process:

```
pmap -d <PID>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this little hamster in Perl for a simple system overview (on Linux):

http://public.m-plify.net/apercu/apercu.pl

Groups processes by name, e.g. all the processes named "httpd" go into one line; or a special process is given its own line.

For each group give:

- total CPU usage used (percent of single CPU, so the total can be over 100%)
- total mem usage used (percent)
- total 'rss', 'size', 'sz', 'vsz' used (from 'ps')
- total number of processes grouped
- total number of threads managed by the grouped processes
- total number of file descriptors used by the processes grouped ("FILES")
- total number of internet sockets used (that value is already included in "FILES")
- total number of unix domain sockets used (that value is already included in "FILES")